# routing scope (":locale") error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.0.9

I configured routes according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

But seems that info there is not full. My routes.rb:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /ru|en/ do
    resources :pages, :only => [:show]
    ...
  end
  match '/:locale' => 'index#index', :locale => /ru|en/
  root :to => 'index#index'
end
```

As said in doc by link above, the routes should be /ru/... and /en/... So, how could I get the value of :locale from the route? params[:locale] is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried, and it works. Try adding something like `locale: "<%= params[:locale] %>"<br/>` to your `application.html.erb` and try different URLs. `http://your.domain/ru` should get you 'locale: "ru"' on every page. What URLs were you trying?

Comment: my.domain/ru, my.domain/en. In both params[:locale] is empty. I wonder why, google don't know about such problem.

Comment: Probably because it works :O) You must be missing something else, your routes as quoted above are fine. As khustochka says, seeing the code around where you're trying to access `params[:locale]`, like the controller(s), could help to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in open_id_authentication plugin. Removing it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it must have been a comment, not an answer, but I don't have the right to comment.

Are you getting empty `params[:locale]` when accessing, say, http://localhost:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/ru ?

Surely, if must be empty when hitting `/` or `/pages/1`, but should not be empty when hitting `/ru`, `/en`, `/ru/pages/1` etc

Comment: It is empty in all situations, /, /en, /ru/, /en/pages/o_respublike. I couldn't find topic here with similar situation around.

Comment: seeing full routes.rb and controller code may help to answer. Especially if you have some custom routes (that can override the later route, e.g. if you have something like `match '/:id' => 'pages#show'`) or some filters in the controller